# Are the Bionic 6 TOTALLY bionic?

Tags: bionic-six

The 1980s cartoon *Bionic 6* basically took the premise of *The 6 Million Dollar Man* and amped it *up to 11,* while adding the family/team component.

[*watch* the first one to see them using their abilities in the intro, but *listen* to the English version in the second one]

The thing about it is, if we look at it in terms of "pure" bionics... *some of these abilities don't make ANY sense!* It made me wonder...

**Are the Bionic 6 *purely* "bionic", or have there perhaps been some other form of super-human augmentation, such as genetic enhancement?**

Thinking about it, this is a reasonable question; even with the mechanical aid of cybernetics and possible nanotechnology, there are simply *Too many unexplained phenomenon* which show how the "powers" of the 6 work. I'll show examples in an answer of my own, but I never saw the entire series, so is there any other material which can shed light on this possibility?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bionic_Six - Their powers seem to be largely based around distinguishing them from each other with psychic powers, energy beams, etc

Comment: I don't know if an answer is the best way to provide an example that the question lacks; you should definitely include that in the question.

Comment: @DavidW I'm sitting here typing out the examples as I speak...adding them in may well make the question itself overly long, which I've found deters people from answering.

Comment: @Valorum and as a super-hero themed show, I can totally _get that_; there needs to be skill & visual distinction for kids to identify the characters easily and identify _with_ each one personally.  Other shows did it better, though, while remaining _within_ the confines of their constructed lore; _G.I. Joe, Thundercats, Silver Hawks, COPS_ ... all of these had heroes who got their powers from the same basic source, but could account for the _vast_ differences in magnitude in some way. I can buy them all being bionic; how _that_ allows one to have **psychic powers,** however, needs explaining!

Comment: @Russhiro - You're approaching this from a logical 2**1**st Century scientific standpoint. Don't forget that the FBI, CIA, NSA, KGB, MI5, MI6 and Shin Bet all wasted millions trying to determine what, if any, powers could be exercised by psychics. These were considered legitimate(ish) fields of study for serious scientists.

Comment: @Valorum and I agree, I may be looking for scientific basis where the show just wanted to have a fun premise for kids to pick up and run with; fair enough. I still don't _negated_ the possibility of psychic powers existing, in fact, considering the various mysterious of the human mind and how some people _have_ been shown to faintly detect radio signals, I would err on the side of it being possible. What I _can't_ sit back and just "Accept" is as a kid with both 30 years of science _and_ comic book backgrounds, that **no explanation AT ALL** is provided to show _how_ these super humans work.

Comment: The thing is, genetics can't do any of the things in the show, either. The major difference is that most people have a much poorer understanding of genetics than basic mechanics, and so they think maybe it can. A bionic implant that allows people to shoot energy beams out of their eyes (without dying!) is no less plausible modifying their genes to do the same. The basic problem is how such a system would operate, not how it's produced. Human bodies are also mechanical systems, and don't get a special exemption from physics.

Comment: For instance: precognition probably violates causality; anything sensitive enough to light that it can see won't react well to the heat or radiation produced by destructive "energy beams" through any physical process; a material that can resist several tons of force applied over a small area is probably inconsistent with the flexibility of the human body; a biological magnet strong enough to move sizeable metallic objects would require tons of energy to operate and extraordinary mass to counterbalance its force, besides which any fine manipulation at a distance would be impossible.

Comment: @Adamant Again, my dude, I'm in _Complete agreement_ with everything you are saying, most of which is covered by limited "SOD".  I mean, have you even _seen_ this show? Not only are there no scars from the bionic surgery, but somehow, _wherever_ they are, they can just "materialize" their outfits and weapons; at least **Centurions** used a satelite in geosynchronous orbit to explain how the gear was _teleported!_ But that's the difference; it went from "Straight unbelievable" to "conceptually _plausible_ at least" with that explanation; no such attempt is made for details in the **Bionic 6**.

Answer (score 1):

Now again, I didn't watch the entire series, so I have no "proof" to fall back on... but considering that their main villain, Scarab, augmented *his* henchmen on a genetic level, and he is Professor Sharpe's evil younger brother, having such biological aid to the Bionic 6's cybernetic enhancements make a bit more sense.  The "Genetically enhanced human" component makes even *more* sense when you see how the whole series started...

**Backstory:** Essentially, in the "near future" of the 21st century, cybernetics and bionics are a reality, and their abilities seem to go beyond mere physical enhancement. One of the greatest Biophysicists and Cybernetic professors, Amadeus Sharpe, uses his friend, Test pilot and family man Jack Bennett, as his specialized bionic super agent, *Bionic 1.*  Jack works for a long time using his mid-level super strength [able to pick up cars and break robots in half], enhanced hearing and vision, increased speed and durability and optical energy blasts to confront everything from terrorists to natural disasters, all without his family knowing.

The episode *Bionics On!* shows what happens: during a family ski vacation, an accident----actually, an encounter with aliens, *a variety* of which seem to exist in this world----- exposes his family to an unknown radiation, injuring them. This forces Jack and Professor Sharpe to have his wife Helen and their 4 teenage children to undergo the "Bionisization" process, giving them all bionic abilities, and making them function as a super agent team. The "process" itself seems less like the "invasive surgery" and replacement of limbs with obvious mechanical parts we saw Steve Austin go through, and more like "controlled exposure to an experimental energy beam" while computers conduct unseen changes with their physiology.

Now granted, this was a kids show, so the science could be hand-waved for the sake of simplicity, especially for something possibly unsettling like "limb replacement surgery".... but this origin alone gives more credence to the "super human" possibility than the "purely cyborg" premise.

While basic bionic abilities [enhanced strength, speed, durability, agility, hardwired bionic control unit and funky 80s battle-jump suits] are shared by all, just to varying degrees, each member seems to have one or two specialized abilities which gives them a unique edge. These abilities usually fit very much with the family member's core personality or role in the family, and make each character easier to distinguish.

**Mother 1** possess precognitive, mind reading and holographic/ illusion projection abilities. Helen is also a skilled marine biologist, so animal empathy of a sort seems to come naturally to her. She's been shown to be able to "communicate" with other creatures, in some way understanding, or (at the very) least sensing their current emotional states.

**Sport 1** is arguably the third strongest physically, but seems to have the best overall *balance* of powers [strength, speed, agility, and energy projection]. His signatures are a nearly indestructible baseball bat [which he seems to pull from out of _nowher_e] and magnetic powers so strong they can move girders from over 20 yards away...

**Rock 1** is the least strong physically (still stronger than a literal bear), but absolute *fastest* in ground speed, running at what the Professor has called "super sonic speed" and possessing twin shoulder mounted sonic blasters. Her nervous system has been shown able to keep up with her foot speed, which makes sense; she'd *plow* into walls otherwise.

**Karate 1** is the most agile, and the quickest "Reaction time" in reflexes, being able doge or grab multiple projectiles out of the air even when attacked. He can also leap several stories, kick through building-sized robots, and sense chi energy. He's also the most battle trained, having studied martial arts from his natural father from the age of 3 or so...

**I.Q.** is physically the strongest, even more so than Bionic 1, and *most durable;* he's been shown being able to lift several tons of rock and steel, casually stick his fingers in concrete, and create a limited personal magnetic field which grants extra protection against projectiles. He's also the technically *smartest* of the group [hence the name] with a mind that can process information very quickly and mastery of several sciences. To be fair though, it is unknown if even the majority of this intellect stems from his bionic upgrades, as he was already a science-minded kid.

Again, the nature of some of these special abilities just *can't* be easily explained by advanced cybernetics alone; the technology would either be *too limited* to do things on that scope, require constant maintenance, or simply verges on the mechanically *impossible* ...

Mother 1's psychic powers [which they are *refereed to* as such in the series], for instance...

Even if Helen's base intuitive abilities are natural, there's no logical explanation given for how those could be "enhanced" by computers, *nor* is there any feasible way for her to "project" mental "holograms"... at least *not* outside her line of sight, which she has done on occasion. If they were using some sort of nano-tech which is *linked* to her, it sounds more probable [essentially, she'd be mentally controlling the micro robots via some type of signal, which would then do the *actual* projecting] but this is never alluded to in story.

"Chi" as a concept is a *spiritual* energy, so unless they have found some way to prove that the spirit exist, then it *shouldn't* be able to be "tapped into"; but that was the very *premise* of the martial arts themed episode *Enter the Bunji!* Aside from the various aliens, the show itself has even alluded to super natural forces, like ghosts and magic, being real, with Bunji's natural father appearing as an unseen "Spirit" to guide the boy in times of need.

Super speed is *believable,* especially machine assisted; the original Bionic Man was said to run at upwards of 70 miles an hour. And if they were scaled to human size, there are some living insects that *can*  run at what would be close to 200 mph. *Supersonic* speed however, for a human, is where things get "iffy"...
Supersonic travel is achieved by any object that exceeds the speed of sound, which effectively counts as Mach 1. For objects traveling in dry air of a temperature of 20 °C (68 °F) at sea level, that speed is approximately 344 meters *per second!* To put that in context, that's 1,125 fps, **768 mph,** 667 knots, or 1,235 km/h. Now while it's common to find bullets that travel that fast, *very few* **wheeled vehicles** are capable of achieving this pace on land, *much less* for any "striding" machines; the energy required for a 120 lb object to reach that speed *alone* would be tremendous! This would naturally then apply to Rock 1's "super sonic" running; even with *metal* joints and built in shock absorbers, starting and stopping at those types of velocities would take a **serious strain** on a "normal" human body...

And that *pales* in comparison to the magnetic forces generated by the others!

The typical strength of the Earth's magnetic field at its surface is around a half a gauss [those are everyday units of magnetic fields]. There are 10,000 gauss in one Tesla. The magnets used in an MRI machine at most Labs range anywhere from 20 tesla, all the way up to to 45 tesla for DC fields. A functional, mid-level MRI machine is capable of attracting 10 lbs of metal from up to 8 feet away. So, in order to lift an average steel girder, a *massive* amount of electromagnetic energy would be needed...and this would be the energy Sport 1 would be channeling *through his hands!* I know very few devices of that size...let *alone* human tissue.... which could handle *That* amount of amperage.

Let's not even *start* on the energy-projection ability Bionic 1 has via his eyes; it's been shown to *not* be heat, lasers or electricity, because while it *can* cause things to explode, it most often *doesn't*, seeming to have more of a "concussive force" than anything else. It could *possibly* be photonic, and his bionic eyes have the ability to alter the wavelength, making it hotter at more focused intensities or output more of a "solid" energy, but that would still mean it gives of *some* kind of heat. He's also used it as a type of "Tractor beam" to draw things to him. Also, electromagnetic interference seems to  alter the beams' overall effectiveness.

A last component to note in this: In the **6 Million Dollar Man** and **Bionic Woman** series, the titular protagonists were powered by miniature nuclear reactors in their limbs, and [at least initially] had to periodically draw off the nuclear waste from these power sources to prevent radiation induced negative effects. That didn't seem to be a problem later on in each series, but it *was* alluded to in the 2010s comic update by Kevin Smith.

[image]

And even those modern comic counterparts were *nowhere near* as powerful as the Bionic 6, all of whom were powered by a rechargeable, measurable, unknown energy the Professor called "Bions." Apparently, this charging could happen passively as well, their bodies seeming to either somehow absorb or "generate" bions, which could take them from their lowest ebb to "full bionic strength" within 2 hours. In a pinch, they could be "Recharged" by one of Professor Sharpe's mobile charging devices within a few seconds.

Given these examples, again, it seems more likely that the Bennett family were all augmented  *genetically* as well as bionically. Yes, a type of nanotech was put into their forms and wired to their major tissues, effectively making them part machine cyborgs... but the level of super-human prowess they show simply doesn't seem to be logically explained by the presence of cybernetics alone. To deal with the energy output their bodies show regularly, the very *tissues* themselves would have had to be changed on some fundamental level, making them, at the very least, more resilient, energy efficient,  regenerative and possibly molecularly denser.

Comment: The problem is that it's no more sensible to explain those powers with genetics (carbon physics) than with bionics (metal physics). When all things are considered, they are simply inconsistent *with physics*.

Comment: @Adamant True enough, but considering mental powers have a "thing" in sci-fi and fantasy for years, I can suspend disbelief in _that_ regard. **The Lawnmower Man** did an admirable job of showing how to "tap into the brains potential" with technology, unleashing plausible psychic powers. No such answers or even rudimentary hand waves are provided _here,_ so I'm actively seeking ways in which we can address that... _outside_ the "real world" context, of course.

Comment: Fantasy is fine, but real-world science just doesn't work as an explanation for this kind of stuff, and I am not sure it even makes sense to try.

Comment: Wasn't that the one where the titular character had telekinesis and could blow up things with their mind? I don't know if that would be a good example of *plausible* psychic powers. Only telepathy is plausible, and only barely; because humans haven't evolved to communicate through electromagnetic signals, you'd need a strong field to penetrate the skull from a distance, which would make anything as precise as a verbal message difficult.

Comment: @Adamant if the very act of _trying_ is futile, then **why even have a site** dedicated to these types of thought experiments and _discussions,_ my man? And granted, we know _more_ about science than we did when this show came out 30 years ago, so it behooves us then to look back on these short comings and find ways to improve them for future Fantasy and Sci-Fi endeavors.

Comment: @Adamant No, that's the one where a mentally deficient laborer was experimented on by a brilliant scientist, increasing his mental faculties 10,000 fold, and he was able to exist as a disembodied construct in computers and _manipulate dangerous items_ with his mind. Supposedly "based" off a Stephen King story, but looks _nothing_ like the original tale. I'd venture that if receiving signals via the brain is possible [it _does_ have billions of neurons which do that internally already], then other means of utilizing such signals are plausible, if not directly _doable._

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100861/discussion-between-adamant-and-russhiro).

Comment: @Russhiro As far as I understand our policies, asking for real science explanations for fantasy/sci-fi elements of shows/movies/books/whatever is off-topic, so we don't seem to have such a site. You can ask how the show/movie/book/whatever **says** it works, but you can't ask how it actually would work or whether the show's explanation is plausible/correct. It's possible I'm wrong on what our policy is, though.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist This, friend, is why I mentioned "I never saw the entire series, so is there any other material which can shed light on this possibility?" I don't know if the show itself _elaborated_ on the way the bionics worked, or if more fantastical elements were straight "explained away" in the show itself. The genetic augmentation is more "a probable basis as gained through observation," but this show _did_ on occasion seem to take its sci-fi seriously. As such, i thought another explanation would be given at some point.